# Issue when using complete path in url AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

i am `passing data to database using PHP - Ajax` but i noticed if i use **url:'xyz.php'** hosted on my `same server`, where i `placed other files related to project`, then able to store data into database.

But when i use `url:'http://www.domainname.com/myfolder/xyz.php'` **(using other server, not where i have placed project files)** it doesnot store data to server ! `WHY` ?

here is my script which i used, please `check and let me know how can i use complete instead of only file name like: xyz.php` (using right now)

```
$.ajax({
        url:'xyz.php',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
        }
```

I hope my question is clear to all of you, just `want to know how can i store data to server, if i am using complete URL in place of File name only`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @u_mulder thanks for the link, but be frank friend not so clear to me, as i am new in development, will you help me to get my work done! In short what i have to do now ?? or is it not possible to use complete url and what would you recommend me to do --- to place this file in same server where i placed other files of same project

Comment: it's very difficult for me to understand, exactly what to do ??

Comment: xyz.php should present in myfolder.
Please place xyz.php file in same server where you placed other files of same project.

Comment: Sorry @NaincyGupta I don't want to place xyz.php file in same server. Tell me another way if you know.

Answer (score 0):

By default, AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) cannot be sent to different domain.
In order to overcome this, you have to use JSONP.
There's a detailed guide of how to use it here: [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)